# Eloquent, search through relationships

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

What's the right procedure for searching (as in `WHERE name LIKE %acme%`) for field values through relationship?

Let's say we have a `Client` model which belongs_to `Company`. Now I'd like to filter (search) via `$client->company->name` field.

I've tried `Client::where('company.name', 'LIKE', 'acme')->get();`

But it doesn't work...

I've got eager loading set up... `$includes = array('company')`

EDIT: Forgot to mention that my relationship is working...

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try using eager loading:

```
$client = Client::with(array('company' => function($query) {
    $query->where('name', 'LIKE', 'acme');
}))->first();
```

Comment: Shouldn't $includes = array('company') in the model be the same?

Comment: From the docs - _Note: Using with will override a models $includes._

Comment: You don't get my point... why would I want to override something that's already set up and working...

Answer (score 0):

Now that I have a better understanding - Laravel eager loading doesn't use JOIN query, which is different from other ORM approach, being said that it still possible to use Eloquent with join using Fluent Query Builder structure. So you won't be able to search by a related model's value with Eloquent. Use the Fluent interface for joins:
 http://laravel.com/docs/database/fluent#joins

You can still use the fluent interface with your elequent models by doing Client::join( ....
You should look at something like Doctrine for this kind of functionality. Be prepared for the steeper learning curve though

Comment: Now that I have a better understanding - Laravel eager loading doesn't use JOIN query, which is different from other ORM approach, being said that it still possible to use Eloquent with join using Fluent Query Builder structure. So you won't be able to search by a related model's value with Eloquent. Use the Fluent interface for joins: http://laravel.com/docs/database/fluent#joins

Comment: You can still use the fluent interface with your elequent models by doing Client::join( ....

Comment: You should look at something like Doctrine for this kind of functionality. Be prepared for the steeper learning curve though.

Answer (score 0):

**TRY THIS**

You can achieve that by using the join method in eloquent.

```
Client::join('companies AS company', 'clients.company_id', '=', 'company.id')
       ->select('clients.*', 'company.name AS company_name')
       ->with('company')
       ->where(function($query) {
           $query->where('company_name', 'LIKE', 'acme');
       })
       ->get();
```

As you can see I joined the companies table to the client to have a ***company_name*** on the return data. So you can easily search to those clients where the company name is "acme".